# Submitting a model to action that is different from view model's type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two models:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class DetailViewModel
{
     public IEnumerable<string> Titles { get; set; }
     public PersonViewModel Person { get; set; }         
}
```

The form is presented with two fields, the first field being the `Name`, the second field being the a dropdown of `Titles` (Mr., Mrs. Miss., etc.)

The view for this page is strongly typed to `DetailViewModel`, and the `Save` method in the controller accepts a parameter of type `PersonViewModel`.

Since the view is strongly typed to a type that is *different* from the form action's parameter type, the names in the HttpRequest do not match what MVC is expecting in the action.

Is it possible to have MVC bind correctly with the model mismatch **without** having to manually specify form field names? (eg. I still want to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Person.Name)`)

For clarification, the form field names that are being submitted are similar to the following:

> Person.Name=Matthew&Person.Title=Mr.

Where I need the following (for model binding to work):

> Name=Matthew&Title=Mr.

Comment: Cant your save method accept a `DetailViewModel`?

Comment: I could, but things start to get messy when I have to do validation.  The actual posted data is everything within `Person` and nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute` in the action method

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix="Person")]PersonViewModel model)
{
}
```

This essentially strips the `Person` prefix from the property name while binding

Comment: Well that was fast!  This looks to do exactly what I want.  I'll accept when the timeout expires.

Comment: I have a question. In general, can `BindAttribute` be used to force MVC to accept any different model from than the one processed in a View?

Comment: Only a subset of the model passed to the view. In addition to `Prefix` the [BindAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) can `Include` or `Exclude` model properties from the binding process. Not sure what you have in mind, but you can always create your own custom `ModelBinder` if you want more control over the binding process