# ASP.NET MVC 4 property-renaming for posting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, extension-methods, model-binding

Follwing convention(s) are given. Each `Action` has a single parameter of type `BaseRequest` with data depending on the `Action`. The `ViewModel` is always of type `BaseResponse`.

What I'm trying to do is, that if a `View` contains a form, the `POST`-Action requires some sort of `BaseRequest`.
How can I achieve correct-model binding as of the `ViewModel` is `BaseResponse`?

I already tried to add a property of `XYZRequest` in `XYZResponse` so I could bind like

```
@Html.ChecBoxFor(m => m.RequestObject.SomeBooleanProperty)
```

but this will generate `name` RequestObject.SomeBooleanProperty which will not bind correctly to the POST-Action which accepts the `XYZRequest`.

Is there something completely wrong with this kind of conventions or am I missing something?

**Update #1**

I also tried creating a new `temporary` object of type `XYZRequest` and bind to it like

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m = tmpReq.SomeBooleanProperty)
```

which will render a `name` of `tmp.SomeBooleanProperty` which also could not be bound.

**Update #2 - additional information**

Following structure is set.

- `BaseRequest` is `abstract`
- `GetOverviewRequest` : `BaseRequest`
- `GetOverviewRequest` has properties of type `string`, `int` or any other complex type and even `Lists` or `Dictionaries`

If the `GetOverviewResponse`, which inherits from `BaseResponse`, is given back to the `View` and provides a property named **`TheProperty`** of type `GetOverviewRequest` binding fails as of

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TheProperty.SomeBooleanValue)
```

will try to bind to `TheProperty`-property in the `GetOverviewRequest` object, which just not exists.

This may would work if `GetOverviewRequest` has a property called `TheProperty` to bind. But if it is named differently, binding will also fail.

I just want something like

```
<input name="SomeBooleanValue">
<input name="SomeComplexType.SomeStringValue">
```

instead of

```
<input name="TheProperty.SomeBooleanValue">
<input name="TheProperty.SomeComplexType.SomeStringValue">
```

**Update #3 - added sample project**

[Sample project via dropbox.com](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50469419/MvcApplication1.zip)

**Update #4 - explanation, why solution from @StephenMuecke is not working**

As mentioned in comments, the solution in other question needs to know the name of the property in the `GetOverviewResponse`-object. The property is named `TheProperty`, therefore I have to add `[Bind(Prefix = "TheProperty)]` to enable correct binding. I really don't like magic strings. And `"TheProperty"` is a magic string. If one changes the name of the `TheProperty` to `RenamedProperty`, the whole binding will fail.

So. I'm now looking for a way to set the prefix some-kind dynamically.

```
[Bind(Prefix = GetOverviewResponse.NameOf(m => m.TheProperty))]
```

would be really awesome. Maybe some kind of a custom attribute? As of BindAttribute is sealed, there is no chance to create one inherited from this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the model that you are using on the page?

Comment: @Robert added the project. Is this helping?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting a model to action that is different from view model's type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070547/submitting-a-model-to-action-that-is-different-from-view-models-type)

Comment: @StephenMuecke this would do the trick. But I'm looking for something more dynamic. Beacuse if one changes the name `TheProperty` but did not change the bind-prefix, this will also fail. Any ideas how to do this dynamically? Something like `[Bind(Prefix=new ResponseObject().GetPropertyName(TheProperty))]` or something similar?

Comment: No, here is nothing built in which will do that - you would have to write your own custom `ModelBinder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by comments I've created some new structure to achieve what I needed.

I created a new class `BaseRequestWrapperResponse<TRequest>` to encapsulate the `Request`-object in a `Response`

```
    public abstract class BaseRequestWrapperResponse<TRequest> : BaseResponse where TRequest : IRequestFromResponse
```

This class has currently one property:

```
    public TRequest Request { get; set; }
```

Next I've created an interface:

```
    public interface IRequestFromResponse
```

from which my `Requset`-object will inherit -> will be used for binding.

In my custom modelbinder override of `protected override object CreateModel`
I check `if (modelType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IRequestFromResponse)))` to see if my `Request` needs special handling. If so I create the `BindAttribute` dynamically and set it before the `normal` binder will do the rest:

```
                var bindAttribute = new BindAttribute {Prefix = GetPropertyName<BaseRequestWrapperResponse<IRequestFromResponse>, IRequestFromResponse>(r => r.Request)};
            TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(modelType, bindAttribute);
```

where GetPropertyName is defined:

```
        private static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyLambda)
    {
        var member = (MemberExpression)propertyLambda.Body;
        return member.Member.Name;
    }
```

See also: [Get name of property in abstract generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636725/get-property-name-of-generic-abstract-class)

Answer (score 0):

The binding in MVC works on a Name / Value dictionary. So if you have:

```
public class BaseRequest
{
    public string prop1 {get; set;}
    public string prop2 {get; set;}
    public string prop3 {get; set;}
}
```

cshtml:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.prop1)
```

Then the object that the controller accepts doesn't matter:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(NotBaseRequest request)
{   
    //do something
}
```

new object taken in:

```
public class NotBaseRequest
{
    public string prop1 {get; set;}
}
```

MVC would bind this with no problem.

So if you want a child object to be bound then you have to have the base object in the object that the controller takes in:

```
public class BaseRequest
{
    public NotBaseRequest NotBaseRequest {get; set;}
}
```

cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NotBaseRequest.prop1)
//<input type="text" name="NotBaseReqest.prop1" value />
```

MVC will use the name attribute to send the value to the controller.

controller

```
public ActionResult MyAction(OtherRequest request)
{
    //do something
}
```

The object you take in can be called anything as long as it has NotBaseRequest in it.

new object:

```
public class OtherRequest
{
    public NotBaseRequest NotBaseRequest {get; set;}
}
```

The name attribute of the html object will create the child object and assign its values.

Comment: See my edited question. Maybe I simply don't get it or it was not clear what I want to achieve

Comment: @KingKerosin Are you trying to flatten the result into an object with primitive types?

Comment: No. The Request can have primitive types and complex types. Event Lists and Dictionaries of complex types. So binding `response => response.ReqObject.PrimitiveType` would correctly bind to the Request-object expected by the POST-Action of the form, so the input-name would be `ReqObjectsName.PrimitiveType` instead of `ResponseObjectsName.ReqObjectsName.PrimitiveType`.
Edited question