# Get property-name of generic abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, naming-conventions, abstract-class

Considering the following implementation of a generic, abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseRequest<TGeneric> : BaseResponse where TRequest : IRequestFromResponse
{
    public TGeneric Request { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any chance to get the name of the property `Request` without having an instance inherited from it?

I need `Request` as string `"Request"` to avoid using hardcoded strings. Any ideas how to make this through reflection?

Comment: "I need Request as string "Request"" Where do you need it?

Comment: Does `typeof(BaseRequest<>).GetProperty("Request").Name` make sense?

Comment: @xtnd8 nope, it contains the hardcoded string `"Request"`!

Comment: `typeof(BaseRequest<>).GetProperties().Single().Name`

Comment: @weston: I don't how this information of where I need it would change anything?

Comment: @xtnd8: Single would only work if it will be the only property till the end of time (which can not be guaranteed)

Comment: @KingKerosin I ask as often people want the name of the property as string inside the property itself. That can be achieved by [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @KingKerosin: I assume your type constraint should read `where TGeneric : IRequestFromResponse`, not `TRequest`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from C# 6, you should be able to use the `nameof` operator:

```
string propertyName = nameof(BaseRequest<ISomeInterface>.Request);
```

The generic type parameter used for `BaseRequest<T>` is irrelevant (as long as it meets the type constraints), since you are not instantiating any object from the type.

For C# 5 and older, you can use [Cameron MacFarland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/672212/1149773) for retrieving property information from lambda expressions. A heavily-simplified adaptation is given below (no error-checking):

```
public static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TProperty>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyLambda)
{
    var member = (MemberExpression)propertyLambda.Body;
    return member.Member.Name;
}
```

You can then consume it like so:

```
string propertyName = GetPropertyName((BaseRequest<ISomeInterface> r) => r.Request);
// or //
string propertyName = GetPropertyName<BaseRequest<ISomeInterface>, ISomeInterface>(r => r.Request);
```

Comment: I have a generic constraint that TGeneric must inherit ISomeInterface, so object is not allowed here.

Comment: @KingKerosin: In that case, use `BaseRequest<ISomeInterface>` instead of `BaseRequest<object>`, and the above code should work. Again, it does not matter that `ISomeInterface` is an interface or abstract.

Comment: nameof is not an option (at least not for me) as of using C# 5

Comment: That's understandable; C# 6 was only released 6 days ago. I just wanted to future-proof my answer.

Comment: Your answer awesome for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate a little more on what it is you're trying to achieve? It looks like you're making requests to web API, for what purpose are you wanting the name of the property and in what context?

This will get you the names of all of the properties in an object type:

```
var properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Select(p => p.Name);
```

Comment: I'm trying to set the `BindAttribute`s Prefix-value to the name of the property `"Request"` without using hardcoded string. See the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616609/asp-net-mvc-4-property-renaming-for-posting